# Alpha shapes from weighted Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to solve alpha shapes from weighted delaunay triangulation (assuming we have weighted DT) in 2D and 3D. I've looked at a few online links that provide complicated explanations. It'll be great if i can get pseudo code of the algorithm with good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CGAL that provides both 3D and 2D weighted alpha-shapes.

Examples in 3D are available [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_3/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_42.5.3) and [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_3/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_42.5.4).
The 2D case is similar.

Comment: I am actually interested in the algorithm that can be used to solve the problem, not in using CGAL for an application. Pseudo code of an algorithm to compute 3D weighted alpha shapes would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Alpha shapes is alpha value and every edges exceeding alpha. Hence you can remove those edges. I don't think it needs dt. a weighted dt.